# What happens to a thread if FreeOnTerminate=true and an exception is thrown in OnTerminate?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

Given this example, how do we ensure that the thread instance has been freed? What happens to the thread instance when Thread.FreeOnTerminate=true and you blow up in your Thread.OnTerminate event? Is the thread orphaned unless you handle the exception and free the thread explicitey in OnTerminate?

```
// Thread constructor

constructor TMyThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  Self.FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

// TMyThread OnTerminate event

procedure TMyThread.OnTerminate(Sender: TObject);
var o: TObject;     
begin
  o:=nil;
  showmessage(o.classname); // guaranteed AV
end;
```

Comment: Free does not AV on a nil pointer. Destroy would AV on a nil pointer. The fact that Free is well-behaved when it comes to nil pointers is in fact the reason always to use Free instead of using Destroy directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should handle all exceptions in your OnTerminate handler because an unhandled exception will cause that the instance of the thread will not be freed (see `Classes.ThreadProc` implementation).
Just enclose the body of your handler in `try`..`except` and handle all exceptions.

But your example for 'guaranteed AV' is wrong: `Free` does not cause an AV if the instance is nil.

Comment: After I posted the question I realized I should check the VCL and I also saw the code in Classes.ThreadProc implementation (in D5 and XE) that you referred to, so I coded accordingly. Tnx. (Fixed the AV example up there.). But it surprises me that they didn't put that code in a finally block to free the thread object when freeonterminate=true, regardless of what happens in OnTerminate. Any explanations as to why it wasn't coded this way?

Answer (score 3):

The `OnTerminate` handler is executed in the main thread via `Synchronize`. If an exception is thrown from `Synchronize`, it is suppressed in the main thread and transferred (via `AcquireExceptionObject`) to the calling thread, where it gets raised again. In the version of `ThreadProc` I'm referring to ([the open-source Kylix version from 2001](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fidA3A6A80177042EC062F444F0E0DF55E154691F27.aspx?s=hook)), the exception does not get handled, so the exception propagates up into the OS, which called the thread procedure. The `TThread` object does not get freed.

The advice not to throw exceptions from destructors evidently applies to other kinds of cleanup routines as well.

Comment: Same in Delphi 2009 - the exception in OnTerminate does not get handled and TThread object is not freed.

Comment: I wasn't considering throwing any of my own in there but it's running as a new enhancement in the context of a very old, large, and highly coupled app with layers of inheritance and nested 'with' blocks, so I'm never quite sure when and where I'm going to get bitten. Just this afternoon I found an insidious exception eater that caused me a good deal of grief...

Answer (score 0):

setting FreeOnTerminate causes a problem if the constructor were to fail later.  It's because it frees the thread once because the constructor failed and then again because of FreeOnTerminate being set.

solution:  move it to the Execute method or set it at the end of the constructor where any risky activities were already safely completed...

```
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    m_bFreedAlready:boolean;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TMyThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(false);

  FreeOnTerminate:=true;

  // something went wrong
  raise Exception.Create('Error Message');
end;

destructor TMyThread.Destroy;
begin
  if m_bFreedAlready then
    MessageBox(0, 'error', 'oops; freed a second time--soon we will have an error!', 0);

  m_bFreedAlready:=true;

  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;

end;
```

Using XE3.

Comment: This is not an answer - it is a (one line) comment. Please make it comment.

Comment: I would have liked to make it a comment but I would think a comment would destroy the readability of the code.  If that's a "big problem" for you, I suggest you delete my valuable comment.

Comment: The code is not necessary - the idea is simple: Setting `freeOnTerminate:=true` at the start of the constructor is not a good idea - it may result in a _double free_.